# Reorder jquery mobile listview, keeping the click function

Tags: javascript, listview, sorting, jquery-mobile, click

I populate a jQuery Mobile listView, like that, adding a .click callback function for each row:

```
        //callback function when user clicks in a contact
        function startChatWithContact(event, contact) {
            //set user that is talking to
            chatWithUser.ID = contact.ID;
            chatWithUser.Name = contact.Name;
            chatWithUser.Patent = contact.Patent;

            //remove notifications case there is any and update pendingNotifications
            pendingNotifications -= parseInt(event.currentTarget.childNodes[2].textContent);
            event.currentTarget.childNodes[2].textContent = 0;
            event.currentTarget.childNodes[2].style.display = 'none';

            //set back to total notification with new value
            if (pendingNotifications == 0)
                $('#custom-back-notification').css('display', 'none');
            else
                $('#custom-back-notification').css('display', 'inline');

            $('#custom-back-notification').text(pendingNotifications);

            //set user info in the chat page
            if (chatWithUser.ID % 2 == 0) {
                $('#custom-message-status').removeClass('status-offline');
                $('#custom-message-status').addClass('status-online');
            }
            else {
                $('#custom-message-status').removeClass('status-online');
                $('#custom-message-status').addClass('status-offline');
            }
            $('#custom-message-name').text(contact.Name);
            $('#custom-message-patent').text(contact.Patent);

            //get message from contact in server and add it
            $.post("api/Chat/GetMessageList", { myID: currentUser.ID, toID: chatWithUser.ID }, function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    $('#custom-messages-listview').empty();
                    $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                        addMessageToList(item);
                    });
                }
            }, 'json');
        }

        //function to add contact in contactList
        function addContactToList(contact) {
            $('#custom-contacts-listview')
                .append($('<li/>', {})
                    .append($('<a/>', {
                        'href': '#custom-messages-page',
                        'class': 'list-cell',
                        'data-transition': 'slide'
                    })
                    .click(function (event) {
                        startChatWithContact(event, contact);
                    })
                    .append($('<div>', {
                        'class': contact.ID % 2 == 0 ? 'status-online' : 'status-offline'
                    }))
                    .append($('<div>', {
                        'class': 'contact-description'
                    })
                        .append($('<h2>', {
                            'text': contact.Name
                        }))
                        .append($('<p>', {
                            'text': contact.Patent
                        }))
                        .append($('<div>', {
                            'text': contact.ID,
                            'style': 'display: none'
                        })))
                    .append($('<div>', {
                        'class': 'notification',
                        'style': 'display: none',
                        'text': '0'
                    }))));
            $('#custom-contacts-listview').listview('refresh');
        }
```

This is working perfectly! But now, I want to order the listView, alphabetically because there is no way the server can send me it in the right order. So I did the sortList function that I call in the end when stop populating.

```
         function sortList(ul, firstID) {
            if (typeof ul == "string")
                ul = document.getElementById(ul);

            // Idiot-proof, remove if you want
            if (!ul) {
                return;
            }

            // Get the list items and setup an array for sorting
            var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
            var vals = [];

            // Populate the array
            for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
                    vals[lis[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].textContent] = lis[i].innerHTML;
            }

            // Sort it
            var keys = [];

            for(var key in vals){
                if(vals.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    keys.push(key);
                }
            }

            // sort keys
            keys.sort();

            // Change the list on the page
            $.each(keys, function (i, key) {
                lis[i].innerHTML = vals[key];
            });
        }
```

But because I add the click listener with $(...).click method of jQuery, after I sort the list, I´m loosing the .click callback. How can i fix that?

Thanks in regards,

Comment: wouldn't be easier to save `contact` inside `a` tag as a custom `data-stuff` attribute and call it `$(document).on("click", "li a", function () { var contact = $(this).data("stuff"); startChatWithContact(event, contact); });`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VNTK5/ like this

Comment: yeeeps it worked! thank you Omar!